# My update while cicle doesn't ask the new data and switch the old

Tags: c

When I try to update my txt data file it doesn't update. How do I fix it? The program is a CRUD program with functionary data.

```
//UPDATE
FILE *fp2;

//Abre o ficheiro txt em modo de leitura
fp2 = fopen(FILENAME, "r+");

while (another == 'S') {

    printf("Indique o codigo de funcionario que desja alterar [0-100]: ");
    scanf(" %s", funcname);
    rewind(fp2);

    while (fread(&e, recsize, 1, fp2) == 1) {

        //Verificar se o nome de funcionario existe (funcname) para dar update ao dados do funcionario em questao
        if (strcmp(e.nome, funcname) == 0) {
```

when we check out the txt file after responding at the questions below, it shows a lot of aleatory caracteres.

```
            printf("\nenter new name,age & gs");
            scanf("%d %s %d %d %s %d", &e.codigo1[0], &e.nome, &e.idade[0], &e.numero_telefone[0], &e.estado_civil, &e.numero_dependentes[0]);
            fseek(fp2, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&e, recsize, 1, fp2);

            break;
        }
    }
     //pergunta se desejamos alterar mais alguma variavel para alem do codigo do funcionario.
    printf("\nDeseja efetuar mais alguma alteracao (S/N)");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %c", &another);

}

//Fechar conexões com o ficheiro
fclose(fp2);
[output problem][1]
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `fopen` to verify that the file was successfully opened?

Comment: I don't understand. Did you try to use fread and fwrite on a text file? "r+" is wrong and should be "r+b" for a file handled with fread and fwrite.

Comment: The description is unclear. Largely because the code is incomplete and the results are not clearly given. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - What do you think this does?

Comment: Did you check the return value from `scanf()` ***to see if you actually read any input***?

Comment: If your compiler is not VS, then `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: ... And using `%s` in `scanf` is not wise - buffer overruns